# How can I close a card on click outside of it in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a context menu.

This is my html:

```html
<nb-user  (click)="openMenuBar()" [onlyPicture]="userPictureOnly" [name]="user?.userName">
</nb-user>

<nb-card class="context-menu" >
  <nb-menu *ngIf="menuOpened"  [items]="userMenu" autoCollapse="true">
  </nb-menu> 
</nb-card>
```

.ts

```js
menuOpened = false;

openMenuBar() {
    this.menuOpened = !this.menuOpened;
    if (this.menuOpened === true) {
        (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('nb-layout-column')).style.filter = 'blur(10px)';
    } else {
        (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('nb-layout-column')).style.filter = 'unset';
    }
}
```

I blurred the background as well. The issue is that when I click on the background of the `nb-card` (`menu-bar`), the other buttons on the background are also clickable.

What I want to happen: When I click outside of the menu card, the card (`menu-bar`) should close.

How can I do that?

Comment: produce a stackblitz so that we can help you.

Comment: @programoholic https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ex68ve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Help me

Comment: were you able to solve it ?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with a custom directive.

Create a new file with the following:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[clickElsewhere]'})
export class ClickElsewhereDirective {

  @Output()
  clickElsewhere = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onDocumentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    const targetElement = event.target as HTMLElement;

    if (targetElement && !this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement)) {
      this.clickElsewhere.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `module.ts` file, add `ClickElsewhereDirective` to your declarations.

Then, add the directive to your menu:

```
  <nb-card class="context-menu" >
        <nb-menu
            (clickElsewhere)="closeMenuBar()" 
            *ngIf="menuOpened"  [items]="userMenu" autoCollapse="true"
        >
        </nb-menu> 
      </nb-card>
```

Finally, add your `closeMenuBar()` function to set `menuOpened` to false, and anything else you want it to do.

The way this directive works is by listening for any click events that happen outside of the component it's applied to, like outside of your menu, and then emits an event that you bind to your menu close function.

Comment: `@Directive({selector: '[clickElsewhere]'})` this gives me error. I already added my ClassName to declarations of module.ts

I put like this 
`@Directive({selector: '[clickElsewhere]'})

@Component({
  selector: "ngx-header",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

`

Comment: The error is `The class 'HeaderComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'ThemeModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `Renderer2`. Read more about it from [**Here**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2)

Do following changes :

- import following packages :

  ```
     import { Component,Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  ```
- Register for `click` method in the constructor as follows :

  ```
  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {

   this._renderer.listen('window', 'click', (e: Event) => {
     /**
      * This events get called by all clicks on the page
      */

     /**
      * This conditon will prevent execution when you click on button
      * If we don't check this, all clicks (even on the toggle button) gets into
      */
     if (
       e.target !== this.toggleButton.nativeElement &&
       e.target !== this.menu.nativeElement
     ) {
       this.menuOpened = false;
     }
   });}
  ```
- This method will listen to every click event on the page. Now You need to add the selectors in the `HTML` :

  ```
   <button (click)="openMenuBar()"  #toggleButton> click me</button>

    <div class="context-menu">
      <div *ngIf="menuOpened" #menu>
        This should disappear when i click outside of the click-me button
      </div>
    </div>
  ```

  That's it. Now your component will listen to click events and when the source is not the button or the card itself, it will set the value of `menuOpened` to `false`.

Here is the [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evyjr6?file=src/app/app.component.html)